# Numeric lettrine is too small

Tags: alignment, lettrine

I'm using the `lettrine` package to create drop numerals as are used in a number of religious texts, but the number is coming out too short.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertine} % this is the font I'm using
\usepackage{lipsum}    % for generated text

\begin{document}
    \lettrine{1}{}
    \lipsum[5] % generate sample text
\end{document}
```

The above code produces this output. Notice that the numeral 1, while aligned with the bottom of the second line, is not aligned with the top of the first. I suspect this is because in the Libertine font, numerals are shorter than capital letters.

[image: MWE output]

This is my desired output. Notice that the numeral 1 is aligned with the bottom of the second line and the top of the first. This looks much better in my opinion.

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

the `0.3` here makes it 30% bigger which might be a bit too much, adjust to taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertine} % this is the font I'm using
\usepackage{lipsum}    % for generated text

\begin{document}
    \lettrine[loversize=0.3]{1}{}
    \lipsum[5] % generate sample text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha! `0.2` seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a modified version of Bernard's answer (I cannot reproduce his output).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertine} % this is the font I'm using
\usepackage{lipsum} % for generated text

\renewcommand*{\LettrineSecondString}{\strut}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.5em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}% this would be added to the findent

\begin{document}

\lettrine{1}{}\lipsum[5] % generate sample text

\end{document}
```

Note that you should leave no space after `\lettrine{1}{}`.

This way you need not guess appropriate values for `loversize` (and so not break `parallel` with XeLaTeX.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem doesn't come from the font, but from the fact that \lettrine expects a second argument, which is by default in small caps.  You can change that with `\LettrineSecondString`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand*{\LettrineSecondString}{F}
\usepackage{libertine} % this is the font I'm using
\usepackage{lipsum} % for generated text
\begin{document}

    \lettrine[nindent=0.25em]{1}{}
    \lipsum[5] % generate sample text

\end{document}
```

[image]g

Comment: I can't reproduce your output.

Comment: With this very code???  B.t.w., I've seen I had forgotten to align the first two  lines of text, which I've fixed. Do we have the same version of lettrine? Mine is 2.23.

Comment: Same version. I get a smaller 1 with both pdflatex and xelatex